# reloadData not calling cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My project uses a Split View Controller containing a table view with a list of class periods and a main view detailing the class periods.  When the app first loads up, there are no entries in the table view and the main view shows a login screen.  When the user logs in, the table view is supposed to reload with text containing the title of each class period.  I am unable to get the data to reload correctly.

When the login button is pressed a message is sent to the App delegate...

```
- (IBAction)login:(id)sender
{
    if([self.appDelegate validateUsername:self.usernameField.text validatePassword:self.passwordField.text]) {
        NSLog(@"Login Successful!");
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginSegue" sender:sender];
    }else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login" message:@"Unsuccessful :(" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

...which checks to see if the username information is valid.  If it is, a segue in the main view is performed.
The validate username method looks like this:

```
- (BOOL)validateUsername:(NSString *)username validatePassword:(NSString *)password
{
    // The "username isEqualToString" is placeholder.  This message will request a login and proceed if the login is successful
    if([username isEqualToString:@"username"] && [password isEqualToString:@"password"]) {
        self.student = [SCHStudent newStudentWithName:@"Random Student"];
        [self loadData];
        return YES;
    }else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

[self loadData] loads an array of class periods to show in the table view:

```
- (void)loadData
{
    [self.student.classPeriods addObject:[SCHClassPeriod newClassPeriodWithTeacher:@"Teacher1" periodNumber:1]];
    [self.student.classPeriods addObject:[SCHClassPeriod newClassPeriodWithTeacher:@"Teacher2" periodNumber:2]];
    [self.student.classPeriods addObject:[SCHClassPeriod newClassPeriodWithTeacher:@"Teacher3" periodNumber:3]];
    [self.student.classPeriods addObject:[SCHClassPeriod newClassPeriodWithTeacher:@"Teacher4" periodNumber:4]];
    [self.student.classPeriods addObject:[SCHClassPeriod newClassPeriodWithTeacher:@"Teacher5" periodNumber:5]];
    [self.student.classPeriods addObject:[SCHClassPeriod newClassPeriodWithTeacher:@"Teacher6" periodNumber:6]];
    [self.tableViewController loadLoginData];
}
```

and [self.tableViewController loadLoginData] is found in the my table view controller and looks like this.  **THIS IS WHERE I AM STUCK**.

```
- (void)loadLoginData
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    NSLog(@"loadLoginData");
}
```

I know this method is being called, and as a result re-calling numberOfRowsInSection.

numberOfRowsInSection:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    self.classPeriods = self.appDelegate.student.classPeriods;
    NSLog(@"numberOfRowsInSection returns %ld", (long)self.classPeriods.count);

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return self.classPeriods.count;
}
```

cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"prototypeCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    SCHClassPeriod *tempPeriod = [self.classPeriods objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"cellForRowAtIndexPath returns %@", tempPeriod.teacher);

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = tempPeriod.teacher;

    return cell;
}
```

The only message not being called is the cellForRowAtIndexPath.  It is not originally called because there are no objects in the classPeriods array.  This is intentional.  However, I need cellForRowAtIndexPath to be called when reloadData is called and its not even though numberOfRowsInSection is.

Sorry for the code dump.  I want to make sure all the information necessary to answer this question is present.  I've been working on this problem for a couple of days now and all similar questions to this seem to be specific to each project.

**EDIT:**
Console Log:

```
numberOfRowsInSection returns 0

numberOfRowsInSection returns 6

loadLoginData

Login Successful!
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using the app delegate for this. The view controller should get the data itself or you should have a data controller to do it.

Comment: Log out what you're returning in numberOfRowsInSection:. Is it still 0 when you're expecting it to be something else?

Comment: When the app first starts up it logs 0.  After login it returns 6.  Also, thanks for the comment, Wain.  After I solve this problem I'll clean up my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `reloadData` doesn't call `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, then **you haven't linked up the datasource** or are **not talking to the correct table.**

Comment: Or the cell identifiers don't match

Answer (score 3):

I figured mine out. **I connected everything via Storyboard Connections Inspector**, but the tutorial that taught me this also told me to add this to the class's `viewDidLoad` :

```
self.tableView.delegate = self;

self.tableView.dataSource = self;
```

When I **deleted** these two lines of code, everything worked like a charm!

Now I call the `[self.tableView reloadData]` method in the `viewWillAppear` and it works even when going back and forth through segues.

Hope this helped anyone!

Comment: when I make viewController on UItableView
this solution sweet for me.

Answer (score 0):

In the storyboard drag the from the UItableview to the property called `tableView` so that when you call  `[self.tableView reloadData]` the outlet will know which table to reload

Comment: Would the table view property be located in the interface of the table view controller?

Comment: After further tests the issue is not that the correct table view isn't being called.  I am able to load the table view with initial values that display properly and reloadData is being sent to the correct object.  I think that William is right, the datasource isn't linked up correctly.  The bad news is I'm not entirely sure how to do that.  If someone could tell me that would be pretty cool.

Comment: @user3105870 you are using a UIViewController? you will need to drag datasource, and delegate to the ViewController

Comment: I am using a UITableViewController.  Right now I have UITableViewController set as the delegate and data source for the table view.

Comment: but what about the referecing outlet that is the most important one, in inspector tab you should these 3 connection @user3105870

Comment: In the Table View Controller there are two referencing outlets, both of which are the Table View.  In the Table View there is one referencing outlet, the Table View Controller.

Comment: @user3105870 basically in the attribute inspector you should see only 3 connections: the delagate , the datasource and the outlet. if you have 2 outlets then thats the issue

Comment: Table View Controller has 4 (tableView, view, dataSource, delegate), Table View has 3 (dataSource, delegate, tableView).

Comment: so it's duplicated, if you used a tableViewController you didnt have to recreate it, remove them it will work