# Table View ReloadData function not triggering cellForRowAtIndexPath Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have seen similar questions asked here but none are very helpful to me specifically.

I am implementing a search bar in my table view and it looks like all is well and there aren't any errors. I have looked through the code a few times and can't find any mistakes. So I began to debug.

Here is my Search function:

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    var filtered:[Room] = filterz(rooms, txt: searchText)

    //println(filtered.count)

    if(filtered.count == 0){
        searchActive = false
    } else {
        searchActive = true
    }

    self.tView.reloadData()
}
```

I can see that this is working perfectly up as it is printing out the correct count.
However I'm unsure about the reloadData function.
I figured that it would trigger the cellForRowAtIndexPath function which is here:

```
func  tableView(tableView:UITableView,cellForRowAtIndexPathindexPath:NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("RoomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    var room:Room = rooms[indexPath.row]

    if(searchActive){
        room = filtered[indexPath.row]
    }

    if let nameLabel = cell.viewWithTag(200) as? UILabel{

        nameLabel.text = room.name
        println(room.name)

    }

    if let sizeLabel = cell.viewWithTag(201) as? UILabel{

        sizeLabel.text = room.size
        println(room.size)

    }

    if let vacLabel = cell.viewWithTag(202) as? UILabel{

        vacLabel.text = room.vacant
        println(room.vacant)

    }

    if let taskIm = cell.viewWithTag(203) as? UIImageView{

        taskIm.image = UIImage(named: room.imagename)
    }

    return cell
}
```

As you can see I have put in print statements to debug, and it is printing nothing. Is this because the function is not triggered or because there is a problem with my code?

If so, can anyone locate it? All I know for sure is that up till the `reloadData()` function call everything is working perfectly.

Comment: your are redeclaring your `var filtered` just update the existing `filtered`

Comment: Haha brilliant! Well spotted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redeclaring your `var filtered` just update the existing `filtered` used inside your `cellForRowAtIndexPathindexPath`

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason for `reloadData` not calling `cellForRowAtIndexpath` is that you either have not hooked up the datasource correctly, or you are not referencing the correct tableView.

Make sure that somewhere in `viewDidLoad` you have a line that looks like the following:

```
self.tView.dataSource = self
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23316117/reloaddata-not-calling-cellforrowatindexpath) for someone with a similar problem.

Also, you can make setting the labels much easier on yourself by subclassing `UITableViewCell` and creating outlets from your labels to the cell class.  This will allow you to remove the whole `if let sizeLabel = cell.viewWithTag(201) as? UILabel` dance.